# Sum the values of a column using a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I an oracle database, I have the data divided by "Central, Group, TIMESTAMP, YEAR, Quarter". However, the values of the measurements that I have only existed for the groups of the centers, which means the total values of the centers are not registered, and I have to calculate them.

[image]

My idea was to use a subquery as the following:

```
WITH table1 as (SELECT 
DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V.CENTRAL_ABR AS NOME,
CASE
  WHEN DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V.CENTRAL_ABR  <> 'NA'
  THEN substr(DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V.CENTRAL_ABR,-2)
ELSE 'NA'
END AS CENTRAL,

CASE
  WHEN DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V.GRUPO_ABR  <> 'NA'
  THEN 'G' || substr(DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V.GRUPO_ABR,-1,1)
  ELSE 'NA'
END AS GRUPO, 

TRUNC(FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES" , 'MM') AS TIMESTAMP,
EXTRACT(year from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") AS YEAR,

CASE 
 WHEN EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '1' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '2' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '3' 
 THEN '1'
 WHEN EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '4' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '5' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '6' 
 THEN '2'
 WHEN EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '7' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '8' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '9' 
 THEN '3'
 WHEN EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '10' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '11' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '12' 
 THEN '4'
 END AS QUARTER,

 SUM(  FOMNMN001."IMN_TOTAL_OC") AS IMN_TOTAL_OC ,
 SUM(  FOMNMN001."IMN_TOTAL_OCNP") AS IMN_TOTAL_OCNP ,
 SUM(  FOMNMN001."IMN_T1I") AS IMN_T1I,
 SUM(  FOMNMN001."IMN_T17_MTBF") AS IMN_T17_MTBF,
 SUM(  FOMNMN001."IMN_T21_MTTF") AS IMN_T21_MTTF,
 SUM(  FOMNMN001."IMN_OP_PER_HORAS") AS IMN_OP_PER_HORAS,
 SUM(  FOMNMN001."IMN_IND_MAN_HORAS") AS IMN_IND_MAN_HORAS,
 SUM(  FOMNMN001."IMN_IND_NP_MAN_HORAS") AS IMN_IND_NP_MAN_HORAS

FROM   

 FOMNMN001 INNER JOIN   DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V   
 ON  DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V.HIERARQUIA=FOMNMN001.HIERARQUIA
 AND DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V.DIRECCAO IN ('2000PT')
 AND DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V.CENTRAL_ABR  <> 'NA'

INNER JOIN   DMDO_TEMPO 
ON  DMDO_TEMPO.DATA=FOMNMN001.DATA
AND   DMDO_TEMPO.DATA >= '20190101'
AND MOD(TO_NUMBER (EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES")) , 3) = 0

GROUP BY DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V.CENTRAL_ABR, 
CASE
  WHEN DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V.CENTRAL_ABR  <> 'NA'
  THEN substr(DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V.CENTRAL_ABR,-2)
  ELSE 'NA'
END, 
CASE
 WHEN DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V.GRUPO_ABR  <> 'NA'
 THEN 'G' || substr(DMDO_ESTRUTURA_ORGANIZA_ET_V.GRUPO_ABR,-1,1)
ELSE 'NA'
END, 
TRUNC(FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES" , 'MM'),
EXTRACT(year from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES"), 
CASE 
   WHEN EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '1' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '2' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '3' 
   THEN '1'
   WHEN EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '4' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '5' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '6' 
  THEN '2'
  WHEN EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '7' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '8' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '9' 
  THEN '3'
  WHEN EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '10' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '11' OR EXTRACT(month from FOMNMN001."IMN_ANO_MES") = '12' 
 THEN '4'
 END 

 ORDER BY  4, 2, 3
 )
 Select NOME , CENTRAL , GRUPO , TIMESTAMP , YEAR , QUARTER , 
 CASE 
  WHEN CENTRAL <> 'NA' AND GRUPO <> 'NA'
  THEN  IMN_TOTAL_OC
   WHEN  CENTRAL <> 'NA' AND GRUPO = 'NA'
   THEN (SELECT SUM (IMN_TOTAL_OC) from table1 group by NOME , CENTRAL , 
    TIMESTAMP , YEAR , QUARTER)

  END AS IMN_OC

 from table1
```

Expected Output (getting the values in red):
[image]

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Comment: Please mention the expected result table

Comment: Please, don't use pictures to provide code. Use plain text formatted as code. It makes impossible to work with it

Comment: I can't really read the query, but I can see it is way more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @salam abdeen. Ask yourself: would you take the time to answer if someone sent you that question in this format ? Answering questions if fun, converting screenshots to working examples is not. It would be a lot easier if you had a minimal reproducible test case: the ddl of a table (with only the relevant columns),the dml for a couple of rows of data and then the sql you tried so far. That way, if any of the members of SO want to reproduce your example, they only need to run your scripts to replicate your setup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GROUP BY ROLLUP() for calculating subtotals and a grand total - see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-aggregation-data-warehouses.html) and [examples](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets).  Suppose we have the following situation (ORIGINAL being a table name or a view name):

```
select
 nome, central, grupo, trunc( tstamp )
, yr, quarter, totaloc, totalocnp 
from original ;

   NOME    CENTRAL    GRUPO    TRUNC(TSTAMP)      YR    QUARTER    TOTALOC    TOTALOCNP 
_______ __________ ________ ________________ _______ __________ __________ ____________ 
PTLR    LR         G1       15-JUL-20           2019          1          3            1 
PTLR    LR         G2       15-JUL-20           2019          1          1              
PTLR    LR         NA       15-JUL-20           2019          1                         
PTLJ    RJ         G1       15-JUL-20           2019          1          2            1 
PTLJ    RJ         G2       15-JUL-20           2019          1          1              
PTLJ    RJ         G3       15-JUL-20           2019          1          4            3 
PTLJ    RJ         NA       15-JUL-20           2019          1                         
PTLN    SN         G1       15-JUL-20           2019          1          5            5 
PTLN    SN         G2       15-JUL-20           2019          1          4            3 
PTLN    SN         G3       15-JUL-20           2019          1          2            1 
PTLN    SN         G4       15-JUL-20           2019          1          3            3 
PTLN    SN         NA       15-JUL-20           2019          1                         
PTLR    LR         G1       13-SEP-20           2019          2          3            3 
PTLR    LR         G2       13-SEP-20           2019          2          1            1 
PTLR    LR         NA       13-SEP-20           2019          2                         
PTLJ    RJ         G1       13-SEP-20           2019          2          1            0 
PTLJ    RJ         G2       13-SEP-20           2019          2          0            0 
PTLJ    RJ         G3       13-SEP-20           2019          2          4            3
```

Query with GROUP BY ROLLUP

```
select 
  nome, central, yr, quarter
, sum( totaloc )   totaloc
, sum( totalocnp ) totalocnp
from original
group by rollup( ( nome, central ), yr, quarter ) 
order by 1, 2, 3, 4
;

-- result
   NOME    CENTRAL      YR    QUARTER    TOTALOC    TOTALOCNP 
_______ __________ _______ __________ __________ ____________ 
PTLJ    RJ            2019          1          7            4 
PTLJ    RJ            2019          2          5            3 
PTLJ    RJ            2019                    12            7 
PTLJ    RJ                                    12            7 
PTLN    SN            2019          1         14           12 
PTLN    SN            2019                    14           12 
PTLN    SN                                    14           12 
PTLR    LR            2019          1          4            1 
PTLR    LR            2019          2          4            4 
PTLR    LR            2019                     8            5 
PTLR    LR                                     8            5 
                                              34           24
```

[DBfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0bf45984a6525643e7d37067b119aa06).

Another little thing: when looking at your second screen shot, we see that you are using CASE ... EXTRACT ... for finding the "quarter numbers".  This is too complicated.  Just use TO_CHAR( thedate, 'Q').

```
-- eg
select to_char( systimestamp, 'Q' ) from dual ;

   TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'Q') 
____________________________ 
3  

-- with your "original" table:
select to_char( trunc( tstamp ), 'Q' ) from original ;
```

See also: format models [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm).